# Footer overlaps the main content

Tags: html, css, footer

I tried over and over again to fix the footer, searched on-line for solutions , nothing worked. I want it to clear the content on the page and sit on the bottom, it just won't work. I could really use some help . By the way feel free to criticize , I'm just starting out and i could use it. Thank you :)

This is the codepen with the code : https://codepen.io/FearShady/pen/YrMvMz

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Lorem ipsum.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="title">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main">

        <div id="text">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p><mark><em>Lorem ipsum</em></mark> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is </p>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CBjij5QgzeE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias "</p>
        <p>On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so </p>

        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>

        <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, </p>

        <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, no resultant pleasure?"</p>

        <p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias </p>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system"</p>


        <p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias "</p>


        <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, no resultant pleasure?"</p>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>

        <p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias."</p>
        </div>
        <div id="image">
        <img src="Lorem ipsum.png" alt="Lorem ipsum" width="330" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="cuprins">
    <table border="solid" >
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
    </table>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    <q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </q>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you understand what `position:absolute` actually does. It is the sole source of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body is the relative position of the footer (in absolute), if i understand well what you want, you should change it like this:

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    background-image: url("background.png");
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);   
}
```